# How can I add reaction with my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm want to add reaction with my bot but don't know how. 
if someone knows, can you answer me???

Comment: Can you maybe show us what you got yet? (`Client` or `bot.Commands`? Already got an `on_message` event?) And also to which message do you want to add a reaction? (A specific one? To all in one channel? To all with a specific command?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message) docs

> You use the Message.add_reaction() method.
>
> If you want to use unicode emoji, you must pass a valid unicode code
> point in a string. In your code, you can write this in a few different
> ways:
>
> - ''
> - '\U0001F44D'
> - '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
>
> Quick example:
>
> ```
> emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
> # or '\U0001f44d' or ''
> await message.add_reaction(emoji)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

Emoji = ✅
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'react' in message.content:
          await message.add_reaction(Emoji)
```

here is the link: [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)